# Can ANOVA be used to study effects when doing a one-off survey?

Tags: anova, survey

Just wanted to check whether ANOVA can be used to study effects (e.g.: effect of age on intensity of social media use) based on the data from a one-off survey.

Frequency of social media use is expressed as an ordinal variable with 5 categories: (1) not at all, (2) rarely, (3) sometimes, (4) often, (5) a great deal